# SSRS report - show tablix only once

Tags: reporting-services

I am using **SSRS report** (VS 2010) and 'tablix' object.

I need showing the tablix only once in the report (it is used only once for the first page, or for the last page, or whenever I like to).

(I have thought to add a variable, and set it while doing the report (like a flag), and check that flag, but I don't know how doing that, and whether there is better way).

How can I show the tablix only once?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why is it showing more than once in the first place?

Comment: It is repeated at each page again and again, because it is related to some data, but even the data is repeated, I want to print it once.

Comment: I don't understand your explanation.  Why should repeats in the data cause your entire tablix to repeat?

Comment: Not only tablix. I will give some examples: There is invoice, and a place where should be a signature - How can I enforce that the signature place (in report may look like Signature : _______) will be only one time. Also, in invoice there are details of person (address, phone, name, etc...) - Those details shall appear only once, on the first page! There may be also tablix - The first line is special (or the first two lines), and shall appear only on the first page (special item, such as main service). How can I do all of above?

Comment: By not having any of those elements in a container that would cause them to repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220592.aspx, table is a preffered way to create some 'fixed' elements in SSRS.

You can use header for fixed elements and body for the variables length.

Nevertheless in the body you can declare a subquery and do any design desired.